# Eclipse class load breakpoint is not triggered when class is a spring bean

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, classloader

Hey, I'm wondering why class load breakpoint is not working in this case. Whenever I set it up and load spring context, it is not triggered. Any idea what might be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging spring beans is no different than any other object. In fact 5 seconds ago I was debugging a spring bean. So the problem is somewhere else - perhaps your breakpoint is not reached.

Comment: Got it, it's the m2eclipse way of not telling you, that "debug run" test phase won't work, unless you set up this property maven.surefire.debug  and let it wait for remote debugger connection...I hate this